# Iloc and rename in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I am new to data Science and recently i have been working with pandas and cannot figure out what the following line means in it!

```
df1=df1.rename(columns=df1.iloc[0,:]).iloc[1:,:]
```

The problem states that this is used to make the columns with index 11 as the header but i can't understand how?
I know the use of rename but cannot understand what's happening here with multiple iloc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disect the line by each method applied:

```
df1 =                     # reassign df1 to ...
   df1.rename(            # the renamed frame of df1 ...
       columns =          # where column names will use mapper of ...
           df1.iloc[0,:]  # slice of df1 on row 0, include all columns ...
   )
   .iloc[1:,:]            # the slice of the renamed frame from row 1 forward, include all columns...
```

Effectively, it's removing the first row and set as column names, which can be done similarly:

```
df1.columns = df1.iloc[0, :]
df1.drop(0, inplace=True)
```